# Android Sqlite Cursur not returning correct values

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have used cursor on sqlite db for getting records .

My code is following:

```
btnnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayQuestion();
    });
}   

private void displayQuestion() {
    db.openDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase = db.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cur;
    cur = sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("select quiz_id, opt_ans from options" ,null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    db.close();

    radioGroup.removeAllViews();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        l++;
        Log.v("value of l",l+"");
        radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        String str_opt = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.OPT_ID));
        radioButton.setText(str_opt);
        Log.v("value of l",l+""+str_opt);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        cur.moveToPosition(l);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
}
```

and the log I am getting is :

```
03-07 18:32:03.190: V/value of l(28903): 1video
03-07 18:32:03.200: V/value of l(28903): 2
03-07 18:32:03.210: V/value of l(28903): 2sound
03-07 18:32:03.210: V/value of l(28903): 3
03-07 18:32:03.221: V/value of l(28903): 3image
03-07 18:32:03.231: V/value of l(28903): 4
03-07 18:32:03.240: V/value of l(28903): 4word document
03-07 18:32:05.561: V/value of l(28903): 5
03-07 18:32:05.571: V/value of l(28903): 5video
03-07 18:32:05.580: V/value of l(28903): 6
03-07 18:32:05.590: V/value of l(28903): 6A process
03-07 18:32:05.590: V/value of l(28903): 7
03-07 18:32:05.601: V/value of l(28903): 7A system software
03-07 18:32:05.601: V/value of l(28903): 8
03-07 18:32:05.610: V/value of l(28903): 8A document
```

and the db which I am using is

```
opt_ans,"opt_id","quiz_id"
    video,"1","1"
    sound,"2","2"
    image,"3","3"
    word document,"4","4"
    appliction,"5","5"
    A process,"6","6"
    A system software,"7","7"
    A document,"8","8"
    hgfhgfh,"9","9"
    hgfhgf,"10","10"
    tytrytr,"11","11"
    ytrytrytr,"12","12"
    tytrytrytr,"13","13"
    tytrytryt,"14","14"
    tytyt,"15","15"
    ytytyt,"16","16"
    ytytryt,"17","17"
    tytytr,"18","18"
    tytytryt,"19","19"
    htghyt,"20","20"
```

Now my question:

Why am I getting video on 5th and 9th index also while having different values at those indexes ??

Comment: Would be great if you could clean up your code. Remove all the commented lines as they are not interesting for us. It would make it much easier for us to read your code this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not guarantee any order of the returned rows, unless you specify. Basicly your results could be in random order. So you need to change your query as follows:

```
cur = sqlitedatabase.rawQuery("select quiz_id, opt_ans from options order by quiz_id asc" ,null);
```

**EDIT**
Also I guess you are not iterating over the cursor properly, try this:

```
int i = 0;
for (boolean hasItem = cur.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = cur.moveToNext()) {
    if (i < 4) {
        radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
        String str_opt = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Database_helper_class.OPT_ID));
        radioButton.setText(str_opt);
        radioButton.setId(i);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        Log.v("Value of button " + i + " is: " + str_opt);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why "video" is duplicated.

Comment: Hi I have added the edited code but we want to display only 4 items at a time on screen and on the click of next button i want to display other 4 elements.By using your code all the data is displayed on first screen only